# Unable to upload a managed package with a generic error

Tags: managed-package, lightning-web-components

I have added a component that is basically the same as provided demo here: https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs to my dev org.

I have then referenced it in another LWC component and put that in a managed package.

When i try to upload my package for Beta testing, i get the

> We couldn't validate your component. Review it and try again.

error.

The e-mail that SF sends me says

> A change was made to the package after the upload was initiated. Upload the package again.

Is there any way to get more details about the error?

**UPD** The same component uploads fine into an unmanaged package

**UPD2** I learnt that the failure happens because i have methods marked as `@api` in my component, e.g.:

```
@api doSomething(date) {
    // do something
}
```

If i comment all these out, the upload succeeds. Except i need them to call them from another component...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i seem to have figured it out.

Seems that if you have any `targets` specified in the `js-meta.xml` file and have METHODS (not properties) marked with @api, the upload for MANAGED package fails. Removing targets (meaning the component won't be visible in the App builder) allows the upload to succeed.

**UPDATE** Note: There is some ongoing issue in SF currently (according to support) where the package may still fail to upload from time to time with random errors (i keep getting the same). The fix is to simply retry the submission over and over. Their support said that R&D are working on that with no ETA.